# If js is disabled hide the same div which is hidden when js is enabled

Tags: jquery

I have an infinite scroller for a product page which works well. For SEO and 'javascript disabled' purposes I need to provide a page which even works with js disabled.

When the scroller works normal with js enabled there's a hidden div with a loader image. Nothing fancy... Problem is when js is disabled I really cant hide that loader image or the div which has the image in there.

There are certain elements that I hide when js is enabled with this:

```
jQuery(function($) { $('body').addClass('js');});
```

This doesn't work for this:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <img src="https://site.com/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
  $(".overlay").fadeOut();
  $(window).scroll(function() { update(); });

});
///////////////// code /////////////
$(".overlay").fadeIn();
```

Any suggestions?

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Comment: Could you include the loader image with Javascript, so it doesn't appear to non-js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the div hidden by default using css (`display:none;`) and then show it using JS. This way, when JS is disabled, it won't get in the way of the content.

Comment: In the css for the `overlay` class, add `display: none` and then use `fadeIn()` to show it and `fadeOut()` to hide it as you already do. The only difference is it's hidden by default and you'll need to use `fadeIn()` to show it first.